# HTML5 drag and drop hittest

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Currently I'm busy with a drag and drop script. But there is just 1 thing that's bothering me, the hittest. Is this possible with HTML5?

I have 2 different images above each other with a transparent background. When I want to click the one on the background I drag the one from the foreground. And that totally makes sense, but is this possible to change?

```
<img src="/images/item.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="item1"> 
  // Lots of these images

<div class="item" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div class="item" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
// These are befor each other.
```

Comment: where's the HTML5 here?  You can do what you're talking about using the `<canvas>` tag if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @jugg1es those are HTML5 drag'n'drop attributes and functionality

Comment: @shomz oh, right, forgot those were html5 specs

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to separately drag the bg and the fg image, you can make a container element (div), add a background image to it, add the drag attributes to it, and put the fg image inside it, as a child.

That way, you can have a common background class for multiple image (I believe this is what you need), while the image inside can be changed.

If you need more flexibility, you might consider jQuery UI's [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/).

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the question correctly... If so, would you mind making a jsfiddle?